# How to correctly insert utf-8 characters into a MySQL table using jpa

Tags: mysql, jpa, encoding, persistence

I want to insert in MySQL database information by my web application. I do it by OpenJPA at TomEE server
for example:

```
public void addLecturer(String name, String surname) {
    Lecturer lect = new Lecturer(name,surname);

    em.persist(lect);
}
```

where Lecturer is entity class. The problem is that application insert data in latin1 encoding. I want to insert it in UTF-8 encoding.

When I insert data by simple MySQL command in command line terminal i get information in UTF-8 encoding.

I have looked at this and I see character_set_server is set as latin1 but I don't know if this is the problem or how to change it:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

---

**Edit**

I have same problem like there:

[JPA utf-8 characters not persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163328/jpa-utf-8-characters-not-persisted)

and

[UTF - 8 with JPA and Glassfish 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189721/utf-8-with-jpa-and-glassfish-4-0)

I add `useUnicode=yes`, `characterEncoding=utf8` and `characterSetResults=utf8` to my property `javax.persistence.jdbc.url` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 2 Steps

**Append the query string to jdbc url**

```
?characterEncoding=utf-8
```

**Run the following sql command on the table**

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I find resolve:

I get data by JTA so I get the data for `persistence.xml` from datasource defined in `tomee.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
  <Resource id="database" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:11080/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;characterSetResults=utf8
    UserName my
    Password pass
  </Resource>
</tomee>
```

So I had to add `&characterEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=utf8` to `JdbcUrl` parametr in `tomee.xml` file (note that to valid xml I had to use `&amp;` instead of `&`). I don't have to add this informatation to `persistence.xml` (only because i use JTA).

Now everything works great. Thank's to **arievanwi** for direct me to resolve of problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with your application, container, etc. unless of course the values for `name` and `surname` in your example are already wrong (which I don't assume). Therefore, it is indeed probably due to the encoding setting. Did you check the information provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)?

Comment: I checked it, but i don't have access to my.cfn file. I want to change encoding only for my database. it's very strange that I can enter national characters by console or mysql workbench and everything is ok, but I can not do this by my application

Comment: And did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163328/jpa-utf-8-characters-not-persisted

Comment: Furthermore, I would check what is actually present in `name` and `surname` before the `persist()` action. It may still be a binding issue from your front-end to the values passed to `addLecturer()`.

Comment: i have same problem, i try to add `useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` but it doesn't help. I debug my app and check that before `persist()` `name` and `surname` have strings with utf-8 char

Answer (score 0):

Is yours a Web Application??? If so check your application server is configured to handle UTF-8 request. In tomcat, for instance, may be done in the server.xml in the Connector section.

Comment: I use Tomcat (TomEE) and in server.xml i have only `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/><Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>`

Comment: So you have to add the URIEncoding attribute like this: [code]<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" ... />[code]

Comment: it doesn't help, i add URIEncoding attribute, but i get information in latin1 (i thing so) :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement unicode correctly and support many different languages, you need 2 configures:

1. Mysql table or database schema should support utf8

   - While db creation use below:

   `CREATE SCHEMA mytestdb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;`

   - OR alter table to some thing like:

   `ALTER TABLE myTableName CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
2. Now you need correct JDBC url and specify utf-8 character set, remember to escape any special characters, as below:
   `spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/${SERVER_DB_NAME}\?useUnicode=true\&characterEncoding=utf\-8\&characterSetResults=utf\-8`

This is how I implemented it and worked for me.